# MongoDB Closest Match on properties on giving portion of a property

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Let says I have a Users collection in MongoDB whose schema looks like this:

```
{
  name:'kantoraketti',
  rating: 1.2,
  matches : 127
},
{
  name:'pengu',
  rating: 1.3,
  matches : 110
}
```

and I should get closest result if I search for name property like:

```
name = 'kanto'
```

even after passing only half name string or end or the start of the string it should give closest matching result

example:

If I pass any of this : kanto, raketi, kantoraketi it should give me result of name: 'kantoraketti'.

I need help to make this search query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a regular expression query, e.g.

```
db.mycollection.find({'name': {'$regex': 'kanto'}})
```